# Yii Framework 2.0 -findModel returns an empty object

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I am trying to show the form values which I have stored in the database.But it's not happening and also returning the empty values.I have added whatever I did.

**Controller**

```
protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = UserRegistration::find($id)->one()) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
```

**Model**

this is my model.I have declared all variables as public.Is that a problem? If I remove im getting error also.

```
class UserRegistration extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $username;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;
    public $Country;
    public $State;
    public $City;
    public $phone_number;
    public $about_me;
    public $password;
    public $verify_password;    
    public $photo;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username','password', 'email'], 'required'],
            [['status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'teespring_id'], 'integer'],
            [['username','lastname','firstname', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'email','about_me'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['role'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['email','username'],'email'],
            [['email','username','password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
            ['phone_number','string','length'=>10],
            [['Country','State','City'],'string'],
            ['verify_password','compare','compareAttribute'=>'password'],
            [['photo'],'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg']
        ];
    }
}
```

**Update:** I have tried `$model = UserRegistration::findOne($id)` also.no luck
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.I have created two findModel and rendered to the form.

```
public function actionProfile(){

            $model      = $this->findModel(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
            $profile    = $this->findProfileModel(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
            return $this->render('/userregister/update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'profile'=>$profile,
            ]);
    }
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

It's `UserRegistration::findOne($id)` and you **must not** declare attributes that are coming from database because these will be empty.

Comment: you meant those public attributes?

Comment: Yes, the ones that are exact like the names of table columns.

Comment: ya some columns are not there in table.i have created other table which acquire all the columns?

Comment: You can mix attributes not present in the table with the ones present there but you should only declare these not present in the table.

Comment: ya i did like that ..how to get public variable values which is not there in user table?this is my problem/

Comment: You need to add logic to set them. You can use Yii magic getters like creating method `getCustom()` to set public attribute `custom`.

Answer (score 1):

Its look strange. This model looks like a **ModelForm** for **User** registration and it doesn`t need to have a table.

I think you have a **User** model also, so u should try to **User::findOne($id)**

If you have just one model for **User** and **Registration**, then you should not set attributes as public if it in table.

So you need just **public $verify_password**, because u dont have this row in table i guess. And i think you dont have the **photo** row in table, because usually photos name is user_id. In that case u should set it as **public** too.

Can u get all your rows from **User** table so i can create a right model for u?

Comment: yes you are people correct.i have removed username and email from public declaration.But other columns are not there in user table.How can i do that?

Comment: no In user table i have username,password,email..these are all coming but other are not coming.

Comment: If u dont have an other rows, why u need these attributes in model like public? U cant save it if there are no rows in table.

Comment: im just assigning those values to other model and saving it.I have two models.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong.

```
$model = UserRegistration::find($id)->one()
```

It should be:

```
$model = UserRegistration::findOne($id);
```

or

```
$model = UserRegistration::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```

if $id is referred to 'id' field